# onError not called when failing to load picture in onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When loading an image in the onLoad (to force refresh of the image). If the image is not present it will not load the onerror image.

How can I fix that?

```
<img class="small" src="VTVFile4.jpg" onload="this.onload=null; this.src='VTVFile4.jpg?' + new Date();" alt="Image not found" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='demo.jpg';" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `this.onerror=null;` from onError, and provide valid image url, and it should work fine::

```
<img class="small" src="VTVFile4.jpg" onload="this.src='VTVFile4.jpg?' + new Date();" alt="Image not found" onError="this.src='some_image.jpg;" />
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9f0yvsu/)